# UILabel in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

While I put a single UILabel into the stack of UIStackView, everything works fine as expected.
But what I need is to actually put a UIView under the UILabel and keep the self-size of UILabel to be kept.
I just wondering, is there is a way to achieve this without using UITableView and self-sized cell?
I used this code

```
let textLabel = UILabel()
    textLabel.text = "zaciatok TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT koniec"
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    textLabel.sizeToFit()
    textLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    let testItemView = UIView()
    testItemView.backgroundColor = .green
    testItemView.addSubview(textLabel)
    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(testItemView)
```

but it shows the text with only one line which is not making the thing I need.

I have tried the new suggestion with the code

```
mainStackView.distribution = .fill
    let textLabel = UILabel()
    textLabel.text = "zaciatok TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT koniec"
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    textLabel.sizeToFit()
    textLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
    let testItemView = UIView()

    testItemView.backgroundColor = .green
    testItemView.addSubview(textLabel)

    mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(testItemView)
    testItemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testItemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

I get

[image]

when I remove sizeToFit, there is no label at all
My constraints of stackview:[image]

Comment: Do you want to add padding to the label from the testItemView?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes but, the padding is asymmetric with 3 rounded corners a one without rounded corner, so I believe I need a UIView under the UILabel to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let mainStackView = UIStackView()
        mainStackView.axis = .vertical
        mainStackView.spacing = 3
        mainStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(mainStackView)

        mainStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-[mainStackView]-(10)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["mainStackView":mainStackView]))

        let testItemView = UIView()
        testItemView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        testItemView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        testItemView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        testItemView.backgroundColor = .green
        testItemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textLabel.text = "zaciatok TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT TEXT koniec"
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        textLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testItemView.addSubview(textLabel)

        testItemView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[textLabel(>=30)]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["textLabel":textLabel]))
        testItemView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(5)-[textLabel]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["textLabel":textLabel]))

        mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(testItemView)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: adding constraints to elements inside a stackview isn't correct for items with intrinsic content size , there is no meaning for a stackview here as yo deal with it as if it's a usaual `UIView`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Without constraints we cant add padding to greenview to yellow label

Comment: there is a `spacing` proeprty

Comment: @Sh_Khan spacing property of stackview is used between arranged subviews. In a chat application that spacing will be between one chat to another chat. Here constraints are used to give space between green super view to yellow subview label

Comment: @Sh_Khan Check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOsv0.png) spacing value 20 is used between both green views. Constraint space 5 is used between green view and it's subview yellow label

Comment: @Sh_Khan Using tableview is best for this design. But OP mentioned _"without using UITableView and self-sized cell"_

Comment: @Vanya Have you added this stackview in a scrollview?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR actually it is in a scrollView, haven't tried yet, but I expect it is gonna work well, any specific reason?

Comment: @Vanya Why don't you use tableview?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR there are basically two views in the scrollView, one is sort of chat, but it is not only text, mostly it is another views with dynamic size, and when user decide, any item with this more complex views have to be visible in the another view, so I believe that UIstackView is better for this kind behaviour, what do you think?

Comment: @Vanya I guess you can use 2 prototype cells. One for simple text and another one for another view

Comment: @RajeshKumarR the problem is more complex, there are about 10 different views with charts, sort of tables , text, so on, OK I can make so many cells, but I need to remove it from first then add to the second in a certain order that is up to the user, so when it become this complex I think StackView is better

Comment: @RajeshKumarR your solution works only for normal text. Do you know how to fix this with attributed text:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810097/how-to-remove-bottom-padding-of-uilabel-with-attributedtext-inside-uistackview

Answer (score 0):

1- For the text inside the label to wrap , mainStackView must be hooked properly with leading & trailing constraints ( sure also with top & bottom for automatic sizing )

2- You need to remove

```
textLabel.sizeToFit()
```

3-  The view you add has no intrinsic content size like the label , so you need to give it a static height constraint

```
let testItemView = UIView()
testItemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
testItemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

4- Set

```
mainStackView.distribution = .fill
```

Comment: I believe that removing sizeToFit() is not the best idea, pls see my updated question.

Comment: constraints up to date in the question